# Separate the packet header from the payload in snort

Tags: packet-capture, packet-sniffers, snort

How can we separate and read the packet header from the payload by snort tool ?
I need only the header information not all the packet, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Only show the IP and TCP, UDP or ICMP headers

```
./snort -v
```

The packet headers as well as the payload

```
./snort -vd
```